# SCM Checkout: Git no credentials specified error

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to run Python by hosting code on Git and getting following error:

> [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (SCM checkout) [Pipeline] git No
> credentials specified
>
> > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

Here is my complete jenkisfile:

```
node {
    stage ('SCM checkout'){
        git "https://github.com/hiraxwahid/pytest/"
        }
    stage('build') {
        sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
    }
    stage('test') {
        sh 'python Tests.py'
    }
}
```

I have also tried saving credentials in the configuration of pipeline but it isn't helping either.

Answer (score 0):

Specify credentials if it is closed repo with the block

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'CREDE_ID_HERE', passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: '')]) {
    // some block
}
```

Comment: How can I create credentials ID? Any plugin that you suggest?

Comment: You will get the exact `SCM checkout` pipeline code using the pipeline syntax generator in your jenkins instance. I see you are not performing a `git clone` either, recommend to generate the script automatically for `SCM checkout` stage rather than typing it yourself.

Comment: To store credentials in jenkins you need to install 'Credentials plugin'. After you can find 'Manage credentials' in 'Manage jenkins' menu.